# Don't open an activity with a pending intent unless an instance of that activity is already running

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

So I am building an app where the users flow through the apps activity is extremely important (must follow a certain path). I am also using notifications to inform the user of where they are in the flow, with pending intents on the notifications so that clicking on the notification opens the correct activity.

My problem is that if:

Activity A Runs, User gets notification that Activity A Ran

Activity A Finishes(is destroyed), Activity B Starts, User gets Notification that Activity B Started

User goes in system tray and clicked on the Notification for Activity A, opening it (Which they shouldn't, as it completely ruins my apps flow)

The best way to prevent this scenario is to only open Activity A if an instance of it is already running. But I don't know how to do that.

Edit: Code for the Notification:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentInfo("Info")
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Why doesn't the notifcation about B overwrite the notification about A? OTOH why don't you just have one notification that just brings the task to the foreground instead of launching any activities. I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how to have Notification about B overwrite the Notification About A. I don't know how to bring the task to the foreground without starting a new activity if the activity doesn't exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the code that you use to create the Notification in your question. I'll look at it later.

Comment: @DavidWasser: This is the code: `
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(intent) `

Comment: In the future please don't put code in a comment. It is impossible to format and read. You can always simply edit your original question and add the code properly to the question.

Comment: If you just want to bring the application to the foreground, you can use the following to create the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`: `Intent notificationIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());`. You don't need to set any additional flag.

Comment: When you call `NotificationManager.notify()` you pass an ID. If you always use the same ID, then the new Notification will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Ohhh thanks. Didn't know about the ID thing. Also sorry for posting the code in the comment, still learning stackoverflow.